# Trying to repeat until condition is false

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to make a loop that repeats until the user input correct information (no whitespaces or blank). This is what I have so far but it only repeats one time. I want it to repeat until user fills in a correct name, e.g. Oskar/OSKAR/oskar

```
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    name = name == null ? "" : name.trim();
    while(name.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Wrong data");
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
        name = name1;
    }
```

Comment: It's because name is not empty anymore.Your loop works only if name is empty.

Comment: You want the user to enter a name and check if he has entered something..right?

Comment: also it looks like you've forgot trim() in the while loop

Comment: @MathewsMathai Yes, I want this loop cause I want to make sure the user enters a real name an not just " ".

Comment: Then use `name = scanner.nextLine().trim()` inside your loop. (you don't need `name1`)

Comment: The reason I have name = name1 is because if I only have name I get a error message on the line String name = scanner.nextLine();
The error message reads: 
Multiple markers at this line
 - Duplicate local variable name

Comment: Why do you write `String name` there? You already have declined the variable `name` as `String`, so you don't need to do that again. Just use `name = ...` (with `String` in front of it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a `do/while` loop so you don't write the same code twice:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String name = null;
do { //use do while loop for this
    if (name != null)
        System.out.println("Invalid Name \"" + name + "\" Try again");

    System.out.print("Enter Your Name: ");
    name = scanner.nextLine();

    //keep looping until name is only letters
} while (!name.matches("[A-Za-z]+"));

System.out.println("Welcome " + name);
```

Output:

> Enter Your Name: 
>   Invalid Name "" Try again
>   Enter Your Name: a1
>   Invalid Name "a1" Try again
>   Enter Your Name: 1
>   Invalid Name "1" Try again
>   Enter Your Name: Oskar
>   Welcome Oskar

Comment: You will miss the msg `Wrong name entered` in this case. Will need to maintain that too I guess using flag I think.

Comment: @AadityaGavandalkar ok fixed

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

When you do this: `name = name1;`, you are throwing anything which the user gave you into `name`, thus `while(name.isEmpty())` will no longer be `true`.

To fix this, you would need to do some extra validation on the `name1` variable, for instance:

```
if("Oskar".equals(name1))    //Instead of name = name1
    name = name1;
```

The code above would overwrite the `name` variable if and only if the user provides `Oskar` as name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like:

```
 System.out.print("Name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        name = name == null ? "" : name.trim();
        while(!"desiredName".equals(name)) {
            System.out.println("Wrong data");
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
            name = name1;
        }
```

Comment: Well you can throw away that code and just write `String name = "desiredName";` then.

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, your code will exit the while loop once there is some non-empty string input. To do more validation (where there are multiple desired inputs), please follow below approach:

```
    Set<String> desiredSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("XYZ", "OSKAR"));
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    name = name == null ? "" : name.trim();
    while(name.isEmpty() && !desiredSet.contains(name.toUpperCase())) {
        System.out.println("Wrong data");
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        name = scanner.nextLine().trim();
    }
```

No need of extra variable `name1`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the second line, name1 is not empty anymore.

PS:You should also eliminate the whitespaces or blank.
the loop body is should like below:

```
System.out.println("Wrong data");
System.out.print("Name: ");
String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
name1 = name1 == null ? "" : name1.trim();
name = name1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start accepting inside the loop instead of accepting it outside:

```
String name="";
while(true )
{
     System.out.println("Enter the name");
     Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
     name=s.nextLine().trim();
     if(name.isEmpty())
     {
           System.out.println("Invalid.enter again");

      }
      else
      break;
}
```

Comment: @Tom edited...I am used to comparing integers a lot..that's the reason `==` comes to the mind at first..

Comment: One last thing: since the `break` is in the else branch, you don't need `continue` in the `if` branch. And your `while` loop header still needs something :D.

Comment: @Tom isn't while loop with empty headers valid in java?

Comment: No, a `while` loop needs an expression to evaluate. You may mean `for(;;)` which is valid as an infinite loop.