# i want the question to repeat but if the user entered -1 i want the program to stop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, java.util.scanner

*i want the question to repeat but if the user entered -1 i want the program to stop ? *

```
public class Q2 { 
public static void main (String [] args) { 
int N ;  
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in) ; 
System.out.println("Enter an integer to print it's multiplication table, -1 to exit ") ;
N = input.nextInt() ; 

switch (N) {
case -1 :   break ;   
default :
for (int t=1 ; t <= N ; t++){
System.out.println (" Multiplication table of " + t );
for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++ ) { 
System.out.println ( t + "*" + i + " = " + i*t + " ");}}}





}}
```

Comment: like if the user entered 2 i want it to start again from the first line but if the user said -1 i want the program to stop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to repeat until condition is false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494337/trying-to-repeat-until-condition-is-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContiniousProgramme {

    public static void main(String [] args ) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            int N = sc.nextInt();
            if(N == -1) {
                break;
            }
            for (int t=1 ; t <= N ; t++){
                System.out.println (" Multiplication table of " + t );
                for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++ ) { 
                    System.out.println ( t + "*" + i + " = " + i*t + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop is a more efficient solution but I will post the recursive solution because it's a good concept to understand. One of the big downsides of recursion in this case is the possibility of overflowing the stack, even though in this case it would be unlikely.

You can call the main method recursively in your default switch statement case.

```
        switch (N) {
            case -1:   
                break;   
            default:
                for (int t=1 ; t <= N ; t++){
                    System.out.println (" Multiplication table of " + t );
                    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= 10 ; i++ ) { 
                        System.out.println ( t + "*" + i + " = " + i*t + " ");
                    }
                }
                main(args);
        }
```

Sidenote: you should really work on improving your formatting. It is very difficult to read your code when the brackets are all lined up like that.

Comment: thank you it worked :) , sorry i'm just starting to learn java

Comment: @GhalaX no problem glad I could help! If you aren't using something like IntelliJ or Eclipse already to write your code I highly recommend it. It will help you with formatting quite a bit.

Comment: my school wont allow us to use any other editor other then jgrasp and jgrasp doesn't help with formatting unfortunately :(

Comment: This isn't a good solution because recursion is not free. There is a memory overhead to recursion, and while it is unlikely that in this instance that the stack will overflow, it is something one should be careful of. We shouldn't teach bad habits to new programmers. Using a while loop (or do while loop) is a much better option.

Comment: @Isaiah You're right, the loop solution is better. However, I will leave mine up because I think recursion is still useful for new programmers to learn. It would be verryyy unlikely for this to overflow the stack, unless they called the method thousands of times, which is unlikely since it's manual user input lol. I've updated my answer to point out the inefficiency though.